# How can I run Bootstrap Alert multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, function

I am using the Bootstrap alert system, but I encountered a problem. My Alert appears when the button is pressed, and then the setTimeout function works and my alert does not appear after 1 second. But the problem is here, the alert part does not appear again when I make a successful or incorrect login. I want my alert to appear on every successful or incorrect login. Thanks advance for your answers. (ı don't want Jquery, only Vanilla JavaScript.) Codepen.io: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/xxEmQLo (All Code)

```
function showAlert(type, message) {
  if (alert == null) {
    alert = document.createElement("div");
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
    alert.id = "alertID";
    alert.textContent = message;
    firstCardBody.appendChild(alert);
    alert.style.marginTop = "1rem";
  } else {
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
    alert.textContent = message;
  }
  setTimeout(function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("alertID").style.display = 'none';
  }, 1000)
};
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#todo-form");
const todoInput = document.querySelector("#todo");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const firstCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const secondCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];
const filter = document.querySelector("#filter")[0];
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear-todos")[0];
let alert = document.getElementById("alertID");
eventListeners();

//Event Listeners

function eventListeners() {
  secondCardBody.addEventListener("click", deleteTodo);
  form.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadAllTodosToUI);
}

// Todo Ekleme

function addTodo(e) {
  const newTodo = todoInput.value.trim();
  if (newTodo === "") {
    showAlert("danger", "Lütfen bir todo giriniz");
  } else {
    showAlert("success", "Giriş Başarılı");
    addTodoToUI(newTodo);
    addTodoToStorage(newTodo);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}


function addTodoToUI(newTodo) {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = "#";
  link.className = "delete-item";
  link.innerHTML = " <i class = 'fa fa-remove'></i>";
  listItem.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";
  listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTodo));
  listItem.appendChild(link);
  todoList.appendChild(listItem);
  todoInput.value = "";
}

// Alert

function showAlert(type, message) {
  if (alert == null) {
    alert = document.createElement("div");
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
    alert.id = "alertID";
    alert.textContent = message;
    firstCardBody.appendChild(alert);
    alert.style.marginTop = "1rem";
  } else {
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
    alert.textContent = message;
  }
  setTimeout(function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("alertID").style.display = 'none';
  }, 1000)
};

// Todo Storage Ekleme

function addTodoToStorage(newTodo) {
  let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

  todos.push(newTodo);

  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function getTodosFromStorage() { // Storage'den Todoları Almak
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }
  return todos;
}

// Sayfa Yüklendiğinde Storage Yükleme

function loadAllTodosToUI() {
  let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    addTodoToUI(todo);
  })
}

// Todo Silme

function deleteTodo(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "fa fa-remove") {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="berkay.css">
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="bal" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="card row">
      <div class="card-header">Todo List</div>
      <div class="card-body bdy">
        <form id="todo-form" name="form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="Bir Todo Girin" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Todo Ekleyin</button>
        </form>
        <!-- <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          This is a danger alert—check it out!
        </div> -->
      </div>

      <div class="card-body body">
        <hr />
        <h5 class="card-title" id="tasks-title">Todolar</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="filter" id="filter" placeholder="Bir Todo Arayın" tabindex="2" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <ul class="list-group">
          <!-- <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                            Todo 1
                            <a href = "#" class ="delete-item">
                                <i class = "fa fa-remove"></i>
                            </a>

                        </li>-->
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <a id="clear-todos" class="btn btn-dark" href="#">Tüm Taskları Temizleyin</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="box2" style="display: none;"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="berkay.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra line to your alert code:

```
......    
} else {
    alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
    alert.textContent = message;
    document.getElementById("alertID").style.display = 'initial';
}
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

Comment: This code is working but it's change the div style. I want it not to change my div style